# Ajax post requests 403 error only for some users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I've been testing my site by having friends try it, and some friends get the 403 Forbidden error on any function using ajax. I'm confused why only some of them get the error, especially when everyone used the same browser. Does anyone know why? I'm using Django as a framework and I think I've done everything in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/)

Example of one of my functions using ajax:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/get_url/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data_name: data_to_send
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //change some html text using data
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: How is it "not working", do you have an errors or a traceback?

Comment: Can you show your data_to_send ? And I see you did not send your dataType within the request. This can made your Ajax did not work. Check this document https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: They get a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Tran, the data_to_send is just a bunch of arrays. All separated, but I just represented all of them with one variable here. I'll look into the datatype thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by making sure all of my form tags had method='post' and {{ crsf_token }}.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get_url/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data_name: data_to_send
        },
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //change some html text using data
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you use this code? In a standalone js file or in the template file?

Comment: `{{ csrf_token }}` work only in a template file, to pass csrf_token value to main.js you should use a form like this:`headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $(this).find('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(), }`